# Ajax Success - ações no momento da resposta do Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Vamos la: Durante a comunicação do AJAX com meu PHP preciso testar uma condição e se a condição for satisfeita quero que a pagina volte para o index.html

```
    $('#tabela').empty();
    $retorno=0;
    $.ajax({
        data: {funcao: 'listaMeusEstabs', idcli: getUrlVars()["idcli"], idsess: getUrlVars()["idsess"]},
        type:'post',    
        dataType: 'json',
        url: $servidor,
        success: function(dados){
            $retorno=1;
            $('#tabela').append("<tr><td> ---TUDO OK---</td></tr>");                    
        },
        complete: function(dados){
            if ($retorno==0){
                $linha = "<tr><td>Sem registros</td></tr>";
                $('#tabela').append("<tr><td> -SEM REGISTROS-</td></tr>");
            }
            // *** AQUI PRECISO DE UMA FUNÇÃO QUE JOGUE A PAGINA ATUAL PARA INDEX.HTML
        },
    });
```

No PHP tenho o seguinte condigo:

```
        if ($intruso==1){
            //manda o usuario para INDEX.HTML
        }else{
            $sql = " SELECT * FROM tbl_cartao"
            $qryLista = mysqli_query($con, $sql);   
            while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryLista)){
                $vetor[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $resultado); 
            }   
            echo json_encode($vetor);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `window.location` para o redirecionamento no AJAX. Veja:

```
if(sua condicao aqui dentro){
    window.location = "index.html";
}
```

Se quiser fazer o redirecionamenteo no PHP, podes fazer desta forma:

```
echo "<script>location.href='index.html';</script>";
```

Ou usar o `header`:

```
header('Location: index.html');
```

A observação é que você tem que verificar exatamente onde seu `index.html` está, para que seja redirecionado.